# Finding the earliest purchase place for each unique user based

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the userID and the marketplace, where the user first bought something.

The db looks like this:

```
userID, marketplace, dateOfOrder
74526,  Amazon,      2/1/2021
74526,  eBay,        1/1/2021
74526,  Walmart,     12/10/2021 
74525,  Amazon,      14/5/2021
74525,  eBay,        12/4/2021
74525,  Walmart,     9/10/2021
```

I need to get the following:

```
userID, marketplace
74526,  eBay
74525,  eBay
```

I tried several ways but neither is returning the result without multiple issues or increased complexity, and I am trying to keep the query as little as possible for whoever will maintain it in the future. Is there an easy way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: What if the user on first time bought from more than one market?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to get the "first bought" row of each user. Add row numbering with:

```
row_number() over(partition by userID order by dateOfOrder asc) as r
```

and then extract where `r=1` (first row = first bought based on date ordered ascending):

```
select userID, marketplace
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by userID order by dateOfOrder asc) as r
  from your_table
)
where r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server features a nifty `top(1) with ties .. order by` for that

```
select top(1) with ties t.* 
from your_table t
order by row_number() over(partition by userid order by date);
```